# Rheem RPLB-030JAZ - is it a Heat Pump or AC unit?

Tags: heat-pump

I recently purchased a home that came with a "heat pump", however when I look on the box outside my house it says:

```
Rheem Air Conditioner
Model RPLB-030JAZ
```

I cannot find anything on this when searching on the internet nor did the previous owners leave me any receipts or user manuals.

How can I confirm if this is a HEAT PUMP or not?
Does anyone know where I could get the user manual?

Thanks,

Comment: Does the condenser run when you're heating your house? Then it's a heat pump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: From cut-sheet Rheem FORM NO. P11-755]

From cut-sheet Rheem FORM NO. P11-755, The second letter (P) in the model identifies it as a heat pump. Most Rheem products are not meant for consumers to service, hence their website not having very technical information.

Answer (score 1):

[Rheem's own website](http://www.rheem.com/products/heating_and_cooling/rheem_model_serial_numbers/) does seem remarkably unhelpful in suporting your equipment. Searching for RPLB there turns up no results...a sad effort indeed. You should [contact them](http://www.rheem.com/contact.aspx) and request information and a manual, and perhaps vent a bit about the website not admitting your product exists.

[This document from NYC.gov](http://www.nyc.gov/html/dob/downloads/pdf/185-04-e.pdf) does suggest that what you have is probably a 30K btu/hr heat pump, though it only gets as specific as

RPLB 030* and * leads to a note of "with suffixes"

Do you have an "inside unit"? if so, look for an access cover on that, which may have your manual stuck inside it (possibly in an envelope taped to the inside of the panel.)